# Where to upload a csv to then read it when coding on Jupyter

Tags: python, upload, repository, jupyter

I need to upload a few CSV files somewhere on the internet, to be able to use it in Jupyter later using read_csv.
What would be some easy ways to do this?

The CSV contains a database. I want to upload it somewhere and use it in Jupyter using read_csv so that other people can run the code when I send them my file.

Comment: can't you send csv with your code to other people ? This way you don't have to upload on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The CSV contains a database.

Since the CSV contains a database, I would not suggest uploading it on Github as mentioned by [Steven K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10836685/steven-k) in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56879551/8044551). It would be a better option to upload it to either Google Drive or Dropbox as rightly said in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56879551/8044551).

To read the file from Google Drive, you could try the following:

- Upload the file on Google Drive and click on "Get Sharable Link" and
  ensure that anybody with the link can access it.
- Click on copy link and get the file ID associated with the CSV. 
  Ex: If this is the URL `https://drive.google.com/file/d/108ARMaD-pUJRmT9wbXfavr2wM0Op78mX/view?usp=sharing` then `108ARMaD-pUJRmT9wbXfavr2wM0Op78mX` is the file ID.

Simply use the file ID in the following sample code

```
import pandas as pd

gdrive_file_id = '108ARMaD-pUJRmT9wbXfavr2wM0Op78mX'
data = pd.read_csv(f'https://docs.google.com/uc?id={gdrive_file_id}&export=download', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

Here you are opening up the CSV to anybody with access to the link. A better and more controlled approach would be to share the access with known people and use a library like [PyDrive](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/PyDrive) which is a wrapper around Google API's official Python client.

**NOTE:** Since your question does not mention the version of Python that you are using, I've assumed Python 3.6+ and used [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html) in line #3 of the code. If you use any version of Python before 3.6, you would have to use [format method](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to substitute the value of the variable in the string

Answer (score 1):

You could use any cloud storage provider like Dropbox or Google Drive. Alternatively, you could use Github.

To do this in your notebook, import pandas and read_csv like you normally would for a local file.

```
import pandas as pd

url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv"
c=pd.read_csv(url)
```